# how to stream my video collection into inet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, streaming, video-streaming

I have a small ubuntu server down in the basement with a couple of self made movies on it. I would like to share those videos with my Family. In my most fancy dreams, I would offer a website with the list of videos to select one and watch it. Let's say, something like youtube but with my very private stuff and only accesible for me and my family.

I am a more or less experienced linux user. I was allready googling a bit. I found Flumotion Streaming server but wanted to get my mind up for alternatives before instaling it. I would appreciate any hints for any other tools. Configuration via command line or plain config file  would be ideal.

thanks

PS: I have a 5 MBit/s Upstream to internet. This should hopefully be enough for one client at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, most web-browsers support the html5 `<video>` tag. So, you don't even need to install flash/silverlight or other 3rd party tools. All you need to create your video portal/site is:

a) A web server software (Apache has good functionality, but lighttpd is quite light on resources. Both are available in Ubuntu repository.

b) Your videos. Chrome currently supports mp4, webm & ogg formats, so your video should be in one of these (See here for full details: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Once you setup the above, all you need to do is create a default html page with description of videos along with a `<video>` tag to stream videos. See above w3schools link to know sytax and other trivia.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I jump in the video timeline without downloading the full video?

Comment: Yes, HTML5 supports jumping in timeline and all other streaming features that until now only 3rd parties supported. To see a demo of it go to http://www.youtube.com/html5 and subscribe for an opt-in trial for HTML5. With this, you can watch any youtube video with HTML5 support, even with all your flash plugins disabled!!

Comment: Cool, seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I only need to write a small script, automatically filling a html page with the <video> tags according to the movies in a folder.